# Not getting latest data from database using Linq and EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am attempting to get data from a database table, so that I can write the data out to an .csv file.  I am using EF 6 and Linq.

I am running into an issue where it seems that my Linq query is not pulling the latest data from my database.  It continues to pull the old data, even after I have changed the data in my database.  The schema of the database nor tables have not changed, only the data.

```
 var cc = new CsvContext();
                string strFilePathLoc = "";


                var context = new SabraToBellEmployeeDataEntities();
                // get employee data
                var queryData = from b in context.SabraBellDatas
                                orderby b.LastName ascending
                                select b;

                // get location path for file
                var context2 = new BellFtpInfoEntities();
                var filepath = from b in context2.FtpFilePathInfoes
                               where b.CompanyDescriptor.Equals("Bell Techlogix")
                               select new
                               {
                                   strfilePath = b.FtpFilePath
                               };                    

                foreach (var item in filepath)
                {
                    strFilePathLoc = item.strfilePath;
                }


                //write data out based on queries above
                cc.Write(
               queryData, strFilePathLoc,
               fileDescription_anon);

                context.Dispose();
                context2.Dispose();
```

The string variable continues to return C:\SabraBellFiles\SabraBellUpload.csv , which was the original old data in my database.  I have since changed it to C:\SabraBellFiles\SabraBellUpload.csv, but my variable does not have that value when I debug at runtime.

Not sure if the issue is with Entity Framework or my Linq query.

How can I ensure that my query is grabbing the latest info from the database everytime the query runs?

Comment: Do you have several rows in the DDBB with CompanyDescriptor = "Bell Techlogix" or only one? First case could be a problem with the ascending, second case could be a problem with the connection and you're checking in different environments.

Comment: You are sure you are not reusing context?

Comment: @XurxoGarcia I only have one row in the database with descriptor "Bell Techlogix"

Comment: @evk i am not sure if i am.  How would I know or check or ensure I am not?  Also I am not sure if this problem is with Linq query or EF model.

Comment: Well, create new context, make a query, check if it still returns old data.

Comment: @evk would i create a new context by doing something like var context3 = new BellFtpInfoEntities(); ?  I am new to linq and EF, so I apologize for not quite understanding what you mean by create a new context.  thanks

Comment: Yes I mean just that.

Comment: Sorry for being a pain but this happened to me some times. Are you sure your config file is not pointing to a different environment than the one you're checking in your DDBB explorer?

Comment: I changed my query for filepath from the one above to this one   var filepath = from a in context2.FtpFilePathInfoes
                                   select a;    and this is returning the latest value.  Why would this query, without the where clause return the latest value but not my original?

Comment: Ok all I have resolved my issue.  It appears that it was grabbing the most recent data all along.  The data, in my case, represents a file path.  For some reason the result returned by the query had an extra '\' in the data.  So if my database had file path of "C:\SabraBellFiles\Sabra.csv", the query is returning "C:\\SabraBellFiles\\Sabra.csv".  Like it is aumtomatically escaping the '\' character.  If I change my database value to "C:\\SabraBellFiles\\Sabra.csv" the result by the linq query is "C:\\\\SabraBellFiles\\\\Sabra.csv"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generically, something is caching the old results. This could be cause by Entity Framework if you're reusing the same DB context.

However if you want to force EF to get the latest data, you can use the .AsNoTracking extension to tell EF not to add the results to the context. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556203)

But realistically, if this works, it means you are reusing the context. Which you really should fix.

Comment: i tried using the AsNoTracking, similiar to the example in link you provided and it is still bringing back old data.  I am stumped